# Is pubsub suitable to be used by client desktop applications?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

If I were to create a client desktop application, I'm trying to find a reliable way to notify client applications of new data that needs to be queried from the server. Would pubsub be a good use for this? Most of the documentation I see for it seems to be focused on server to server communication, and is a bit ambiguous if this would work well for server to client notifications.

If it should work, would I be able to properly authenticate subscribers to limit the topics they could subscribe to? This application would be potentially downloadable by anyone, and I would need to ensure that information intended for one client couldn't end up in the hands of another client.

Comment: Please take a look at the tutorial on [building a one-to-many pub/sub messaging system](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/building-pubsub-messaging-system) to see if this is something you are looking for.

Comment: 1) Are the client secure - can you grant them a service account to use? 2) Are the clients part of your company (team members) or the general public? Add more information to your question on the environment, number of clients and security requirements.

Comment: > Are the client secure - can you grant them a service account to use?
No. This would be a desktop application that could be downloaded by anyone potentially.

> Are the clients part of your company (team members) or the general public?
General public

I'll edit my above question.

Comment: Your update did not provide the level of details required to provide a fact-based answer. You do not want to provide any Google Cloud service to the public without strong security and authorization. Hackers will push your credit card to the limit overnight or consume your API quota causing a denial of service for your other users.

Comment: @JohnHanley So what information can I provide? We will require the user to authorize, and pushing data to the client will only be required after the user has logged in.

Based on what jabbson posted above, we don't need the user to publish anything, only listen for new events to know when they should query the server.

Comment: For example, I asked for the number of clients. Think thru your question and try to determine which details are necessary to get a good fact-based answer.

Comment: Where is jabbson's comment is denial-of-service managed. Anytime you grant access to Google Cloud to any user that you can not control, they can pound your service with requests. Google manages this with API rate limiting. That means your service will stop working.

Comment: @JohnHanley The number of clients will be <10k, and the connections will be long running. The connection will likely be active 24/7.  Each user will be in a small group of <5 and will need to receive events when those other clients in it's group perform an action that the other clients in the group need to be aware of. The messages will be small, and contain almost no data, basically telling the clients to check with the server if there is data.

Comment: The server will be the publisher, and the clients will be only subscribers, so I don't think I need to worry about dos. I would like to ensure that an authenticated client can't listen to subscriptions for another group though, and ensure they don't have authority to publish anything. Is that kind of authentication allowed / supported.

Comment: With ~10K users, which means Google Cloud IAM cannot be used. Therefore, you will need to implement your own authorization system. You have not specified what authentication system your users will use. Google has STS (Workload Identity Pools) that can interface with OIDC providers to provide short-term tokens, but I have no details so I cannot point you anywhere. You mention longer-term connections, which means longer-term tokens. That goes against good security practices and the prevention of token distribution attacks.

Comment: If you think that DoS is not a factor, you will be shocked in the real world. There are millions of script kiddies that get a kick out breaking any service they find.

Comment: If I can properly authenticate end users only as subscribers, then they can't submit data and DOS isn't a problem from the pubsub scenario. That's what I mean.

What authentication system am I going to use? We're likely going to use some implementation of firebase authentication. Likely Google and/or email authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Pub/Sub is not going to be a good choice for this use case. First of all, note that each topic and project is limited to 10,000 subscriptions. Therefore, if you intend to have more than that, you will run out of subscriptions. Secondly, note that a subscription only receives messages published after the subscription is created. If you only need messages to be delivered that were published after the user came to the website, this may be okay. However, with these two issues combined, you'll need to consider lifetime of your subscriptions. Do they get deleted when a user logs out? If not, when a user comes back, do you expect them to get all of the messages published since the last time they visited?

Additionally, as discussed in the comments, there is the issue of authentication. Your client-side app would have to have the credentials to subscribe. This would require you to essentially leak those credentials into your client-side code, which could be a vulnerability in your application.

The service designed to deliver notifications of this nature is [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging).

Comment: Firebase cloud messaging works for android, ios, and browser applications. It doesn't work for desktop applications. Other than that, I think your answer brings up some valid points.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the application to anyone on the internet, you can't rely on the IAM service that only works with Google identity -> You can't ask your user to have a Google Account, the user experience will be bad.

Thus, you can't use IAM service to secure the PubSub access, and thus to use PubSub because anyone could access it.

In your use case, the first step is to ask the user to register (create an account, validate email, maybe use payment method,...). Then, you have an identity, but managed by you, not by IAM. You know which messages are for this user and which aren't.

If you want to be notified "in real time", I propose you to use long polling method or streaming to push data to the user. [Cloud Run is now capable](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-now-supports-http-grpc-server-streaming) to do this and I recommend you to have a look on that.

Comment: We are planning on using cloud run, but these applications will likely be left on 24/7. Long polling sounds potentially very expensive with that method. I just need to notify the clients that a change has happened on the server, and that they need to query the server to get the update. Each event will be extremely small in size, likely sending a single integer value for each event.

Comment: Do you know that with PubSub, the smallest billable message size is 1Kb? Not sure that the price is more interesting with PubSub solution